# debugging javascript - safari hides script behind apples loading gif

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari

This is driving me nuts. I'm debugging a script in safari (6.0.2). The script breaks on my breakpoints (I can tell from the call stack), however it won't actually show the code. I'm getting apples loading gif in front of a blank page where the js file should show. I can step through the code - I just can't see it. As soon as I click the continue button, the gif disappears and my js file shows.

I expect I'm doing something stoopid, but this is driving me crazy...

(I used to use firebug, but I wanted a change, so I'm trying to learn my way around safari - this is so infuriating I'm tempted to give up)

Comment: In case you don't find a good solution to this, I find Chrome's developer tools to be solid.  It might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, for the sake of keeping my acceptance rate up, I'm forced to admit that I'm handling this issue by restarting safari / my laptop.

I should have called IT support :(

(since I can't duplicate the problem, it's not a bug I can really report)